# SQL Server 2012 replication - replicate dynamic database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, replication

We use transactional publication of database.

The structure of the database is dynamic. The application creates on the fly objects like tables/views.

Is there a way to replicate automatically every object ?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new column to a table and include it in an existing publication, you'll need to use *ALTER TABLE  ADD*  syntax at the publisher.  By default the schema change will be propagated to subscribers on synchronization, publication property **@replicate_ddl** must be set to true.  See [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).

Adding an a new article such as a table or view involves adding the article to the publication, creating a new snapshot, and synchronizing subscriptions to apply the schema and data for the newly added articles.  Reinitialization is not required, but a new snapshot is required.  Please see [Add Articles to and Drop Articles from Existing Publications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493.aspx) for more information.